# how do i get http data from a site by scapy

Tags: http, get, scapy

i know its a dumb question. but belive me - i searched i all the internet and i didnt got any answer.
first of all, there is my code:

```
def Make_Get():
        synR = IP(dst = 'www.google.com', ttl = 64)/TCP(dport = 80, flags = 'S')
        synAckAN = sr1(synR)
        getStr = 'GET /index.html HTTP/1.0 \n\n'
        req = (IP(dst = 'www.google.com', ttl = 64)/TCP(dport = 80, sport = synAckAN[TCP].dport, seq = synAckAN[TCP].ack, ack = synAckAN[TCP].seq+1, flags = 'A')/getStr)

        ans, unans = sr(req)
        return ans, unans
```

when i run this function and tring to print the "ans" (first parameter) - its giving me an answer without the data.
look:
Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets

```
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4L
  ihl       = 5L
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 40
  id        = 9784
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0L
  ttl       = 128
  proto     = tcp
  chksum    = 0xc02f
  src       = 216.58.210.4
  dst       = 192.168.233.128
  \options   \
###[ TCP ]###
     sport     = http
     dport     = ftp_data
     seq       = 2116250139
     ack       = 28
     dataofs   = 5L
     reserved  = 0L
     flags     = A
     window    = 64240
     chksum    = 0x77bc
     urgptr    = 0
     options   = {}
###[ Padding ]###
        load      = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
None
```

there is no any data.......
but when i sniffed the transmition in Wireshark, i'd got an html code in a packet.

my question is - how can i send a Get request like i did, and save the html code from the site (to print it, or to a file.. doesnt metter..)

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using [scapy-http](https://github.com/invernizzi/scapy-http), which is a scapy extension that helps you support HTTP.

Comment: i can use it.. but i want to know how to do HTTP REQ without it. The problem is that the answer i get when i do this, is Ack and not an HTML code. you dont know why is it?

Comment: you need to establish the TCP connection first, then do your HTTP request in the body of the TCP payload. So, first a SYN, receive an ACK, and then send a SYN/ACK. After that, you can send the HTTP in the body of the TCP payload, then hopefully receive it